# how to generate functions with changing array size?

Tags: functions

I want to write a function in Mathematica which has two inputs 'n' and 'd', and the output should be (in Latex notation)

$$F(n,d) = \sum_{i[1],...,i[n] =0; i[1]+...+i[n]\leq d}^{d} C[i[1],...,i[n]] f[i[1],x[1]] f[i[2],x[2]] ...f[i[n],x[n]]$$

n and d are integers.

The problem is that I can hard code `F` for a given `n` and `d` alright. But when I want to write a generic function which take in any `n` and `d` and spits out the required right hand side, it becomes difficult as I have to keep changing the array size along the way depending on the values of `n` and `d`. Probably, there is a simpler way to do this in Mathematica?

Answer (score 3):

The `f[x[i]]` factor out of the problem, so the only problem is to determine the range of the sum. Here is one way (naming the function `makeSum` instead of `F`).

**Edit:**

The summation range initially didn't include `0`, but this can be specified as a third argument to `IntegerPartitions`:

```
makeSum[n_, d_] := 
 Sum[C @@ i Product[f[i[[j]], x[j]], {j, n}], {i, 
   Join @@ Table[IntegerPartitions[i, {n}, Range[0, d]], {i, 0, d}]}]

makeSum[2, 5]

(*  ==>
C[0, 0] f[0, x[1]] f[0, x[2]] + C[1, 0] f[0, x[2]] f[1, x[1]] + 
 C[1, 1] f[1, x[1]] f[1, x[2]] + C[2, 0] f[0, x[2]] f[2, x[1]] + 
 C[2, 1] f[1, x[2]] f[2, x[1]] + C[2, 2] f[2, x[1]] f[2, x[2]] + 
 C[3, 0] f[0, x[2]] f[3, x[1]] + C[3, 1] f[1, x[2]] f[3, x[1]] + 
 C[3, 2] f[2, x[2]] f[3, x[1]] + C[4, 0] f[0, x[2]] f[4, x[1]] + 
 C[4, 1] f[1, x[2]] f[4, x[1]] + C[5, 0] f[0, x[2]] f[5, x[1]]    *)
```

In using `IntegerPartitions`, I assumed that you want to avoid double-counting. This may have to be modified if the condition includes permutations:

```
makeSum[n_, d_] := 
 Sum[C @@ i Product[f[i[[j]], x[j]], {j, n}], {i, 
   Flatten[Permutations /@ 
     Join @@ Table[IntegerPartitions[i, {n}, Range[0, d]], {i, 0, d}],
     1]}]

makeSum[2, 5]

(*
==> 
C[0, 0] f[0, x[1]] f[0, x[2]] + C[1, 0] f[0, x[2]] f[1, x[1]] + 
 C[0, 1] f[0, x[1]] f[1, x[2]] + C[1, 1] f[1, x[1]] f[1, x[2]] + 
 C[2, 0] f[0, x[2]] f[2, x[1]] + C[2, 1] f[1, x[2]] f[2, x[1]] + 
 C[0, 2] f[0, x[1]] f[2, x[2]] + C[1, 2] f[1, x[1]] f[2, x[2]] + 
 C[2, 2] f[2, x[1]] f[2, x[2]] + C[3, 0] f[0, x[2]] f[3, x[1]] + 
 C[3, 1] f[1, x[2]] f[3, x[1]] + C[3, 2] f[2, x[2]] f[3, x[1]] + 
 C[0, 3] f[0, x[1]] f[3, x[2]] + C[1, 3] f[1, x[1]] f[3, x[2]] + 
 C[2, 3] f[2, x[1]] f[3, x[2]] + C[4, 0] f[0, x[2]] f[4, x[1]] + 
 C[4, 1] f[1, x[2]] f[4, x[1]] + C[0, 4] f[0, x[1]] f[4, x[2]] + 
 C[1, 4] f[1, x[1]] f[4, x[2]] + C[5, 0] f[0, x[2]] f[5, x[1]] + 
 C[0, 5] f[0, x[1]] f[5, x[2]]
*)
```

Comment: ,Thanks a lot for that! I probably did a silly mistake in the function. The functions f's are not independent of i[j]'s. Thus, makesum[2,5] should give (C[1, 1] f[i[1], x[1]] f[i[1], x[2]] + 
   C[2, 1] f[i[2], x[1]] f[i[1], x[2]] + 
   C[2, 2] f[i[2], x[1]] f[i[2], x[2]] + 
   C[3, 1] f[i[3], x[1]] f[i[1], x[2]] + 
   C[3, 2] f[i[3], x[1]] f[i[2], x[2]] + C[4, 1]) f[i[1], x[4]] f[
  i[1], x[2]].

Moreover, for some reason, the loop over d doesn't start from 0. Howe can I change this?
Thanks a lot again.
dbm368

Comment: Right, I overlooked the lower bound. It's corrected now. Also, I think I  added what you meant in terms of the `f[i,x]`, but I'm not sure if you wanted them to remain symbolic or see their values as it appears in my answer.